# Serial Port, Checkboxes, Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

Hi i wanna still receiving 6 bytes from Serial Port only when is selected TabItem1.
And set checkboxes states depends on that bytes...
Example: but it not working :/

```
private void receiveData()
{            
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)          
        inputs[i] = serialPort.ReadByte();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)          
        outputs[i] = serialPort.ReadByte();

    checkBoxI1.IsChecked = inputs[0] == 32 ? true : false;
    checkBoxI2.IsChecked = inputs[1] == 32 ? true : false;
    checkBoxI3.IsChecked = inputs[2] == 32 ? true : false;
    checkBoxQ1.IsChecked = outputs[0] == 32 ? true : false;
    checkBoxQ2.IsChecked = outputs[1] == 32 ? true : false;
    checkBoxQ3.IsChecked = outputs[2] == 32 ? true : false;
}
// Tab change
private void tabControl1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedItem == tabItem1)
    {                                     
        serialPort.Close();
        try
        {
            receiveThread.Abort();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        { 
        }
    }
    else if (tabControl1.SelectedItem == tabItem2)
    {                
        serialPort.Open();                
        receiveThread = new Thread(receiveData);
        receiveThread.Start();                
    }
}
```

Comment: So how is it "not working"?  What behavior are you getting?  How have you debugged it so far?  What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: WPF/WinForms/or? Why you set `multithreading` tag, there is nothing about async operastions

Comment: Here `checkBoxI1.IsChecked = inputs[0] == 32 ? true : false;`....i got _InvalidOperationException - The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it._

Comment: Side note: Please consider the result of `inputs[0] == 32` for a second. You don't need `? true : false`.

Comment: Somebody edited my tags...i had there different...

Comment: Brian Rasmussen - so how then i set the chekbox state ?

Comment: @hradecek: That's not the point. You're basically saying "if something is true then set a value to true else set it to false". I.e. you can achieve the same result by setting the value to the result of the boolean expression. There's no need to use the conditional operator here.

Comment: @Brian like this ?
`if(inputs[0] == 32)
  checkBoxI1.IsChecked = true;
else
  checkBoxI1.IsChecked = false;`
but that is same with this
`checkBoxI1.IsChecked = inputs[0] == 32 ? true : false;`

Comment: @hradecek: NOOO. Like this: `checkBoxI3.IsChecked = inputs[2] == 32;`

Comment: You are putting the value from `outputs[0]` into all three output checkboxes.

Comment: you mentioned "InvalidOperationException - The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it", you can't update UI objects in that thread, you'll need to dispatch the request, here's a sample http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `receiveData` function is bound to the [`SerialPort.DataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event. This will in fact run on a different thread than your gui. And you like to change something on your gui which leads to the shown problem.

To let this work you should maybe call

```
checkBoxI1.Invoke(new Action(() => 
{
    checkBoxI1.IsChecked = inputs[0] == 32;
    checkBoxI2.IsChecked = inputs[1] == 32;
    checkBoxI3.IsChecked = inputs[2] == 32;
    checkBoxQ1.IsChecked = outputs[0] == 32;
    checkBoxQ2.IsChecked = outputs[1] == 32;
    checkBoxQ3.IsChecked = outputs[2] == 32;
}));
```

This will switch back to the gui thread to make these changes and the exception should be gone.